# How to download Pluralsight videos?

Tags: macos, video-streaming, html5, video-capture, silverlight

Someone must have a streamlined way to pull down Pluralsight videos without using a mobile device or screen capture utility.  In the middle of watching a video, Pluralsight's site went down... they posted something about a power outage.  Watching their videos, cached or not, on a mobile device is inconvenient.  Having to stream it every time, in a browser, is even worse.

On a side note, I tried finding a certain course on an iPad and it was NOT found.  The same course IS available on their site (I WAS watching it).  So, that's another reason for wanting to cache it to a desktop.

**Update 20141123**
I've tried GetFLV, AllMyTube (Wondershare), and Ultimate Video Recorder (Wondershare).  None of them work successfully.

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
As it stands, [`youtube-dl`](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) ended up being my defacto utility for pulling down Pluralsight videos locally (as well as loads of other content).  The command I use is...

```
youtube-dl --verbose \
  --username USERNAME_HERE \
  --password PASSWORD_HERE \
  --rate-limit 50K \
  --sleep-interval 600 \
  -o \"%(autonumber)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s\" \ 
  \"URL_TO_COURSE_PAGE\"
```

In fact, it works so well, that I permanently added a `get-course` command to my `~/.bash_functions` file...

```
get-course(){
    local usage="get-course %COURSE_NAME_FROM_URL% %USERNAME% %PASSWORD%";
    local course="$1";
    local username="$2";
    local password="$3";
    local prefix="";
    if [ -e "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl" ]; then
        prefix="/usr/local/bin/";
    fi
    if [ -z "$course" ]; then
      echo "Problem getting Pluralisight course: Course name not supplied"
      echo "$usage"
    elif [ -z "$username" ]; then
      echo "Problem getting Pluralisight course: Username not supplied"
      echo "$usage"
    elif [ -z "$password" ]; then
      echo "Problem getting Pluralisight course: Password not supplied"
      echo "$usage"
    else
      eval "${prefix}youtube-dl --verbose --username $username --password $password --rate-limit 50K --sleep-interval 600 -o \"%(autonumber)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s\" \"https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/${course}\""
    fi
}
```

**Original Answer**

Found a solution!  Using Firefox and Flashgot it is possible to download all of the video segments in a course. Once the Flashgot plugin is installed, simply launch the course and click "next" through the all of the segments. Flashgot will have logged all of the video URLs. Click download and they are all sequentially stored in the folder of your choosing. MP4Joiner is an app that easily grabs all of the segments and splices them together to create a single MP4. This one video can then be dtopped into the viewer app of your choosing.

Comment: for Windows 10?